# Query ArcGIS Server Map Service with 3857 SRID?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-rest-api, map-service

I am trying to return the polygon a point is within using a latitude and longitude. I set the Input Spatial Reference to 4326 since I am using a latitude and longitude but I am still getting no results. Is there something I am missing?

https://wildfire.cr.usgs.gov/arcgis/rest/services/geomac_dyn/MapServer/23/query?&geometry=-118.031616%2C34.222874&geometryType=esriGeometryPoint&inSR=4326&returnGeometry=false&returnTrueCurves=false&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=3857&returnZ=false&returnM=false&f=html

That is the url I am using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your query seems correct.

There is no polygon at that location.

If I run your query but use `-118.897, 36.065`, two fire polygons are returned.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an Answer. An Answer would span multiple paragraphs and provide an example. Answers rarely ask questions.